# psycopg2 does not execute PostgreSQL function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to call a function from `psycopg2` like such:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="name.host.ex", user="username", password="secret")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc("f_do_action", ["aaa", "bbb"])
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

When calling this function from `psql` everything works fine but using `psycopg2` nothing seems to happen. I get no exception. It just does not call out the function on the actual database.

Also other queries from `psycopg2` work (`SELECT, INSERT`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try committing before closing your connection:

```
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

From [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html):

> Note that closing a connection without committing the changes first
>   will cause any pending change to be discarded as if a ROLLBACK was
>   performed (unless a different isolation level has been selected: see
>   set_isolation_level()).